# how to change layout direction in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using i18next and react-i18library to change language in my react native app, but i need to change direction from ltr to rtl and vice-versa irrespective of device language and save the direction.

I have configured i18n and i'm changing the language but i have no idea how i can change direction

```js
changeLanguage = lnName => {
  i18n.changeLanguage(lnName);
  // change direrction persian -> rtl / english -> ltr
};
```

```
"i18next": "^19.4.2",
"native-base": "^2.13.12",
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-i18next": "^11.3.4",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-native-restart": "^0.0.14",
```

Answer (score 2):

I18next has a [`dir`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#dir) method that given lang will return `lrt` / `rtl` value.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const Layout = () => {
  const {
    i18n: { dir, language },
  } = useTranslation();
  const changeLanguage = lnName => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lnName);
  };

  return <View style={{ direction: dir(language) }} />;
};
```

Comment: i tried this but it made no difference. i'm using I18Manager.forceRTL( true ), but i'm not sure it works fine or not